# Slim Framework - Getting "500 Internal Server Error" for a simple "$request->get"

Tags: php, rest, slim

I'm fairly new to the Slim framework and I'm getting an error in a very basic call `$request->get`.

- provision/hosts - OK
- provision/hosts/28E34748B48E - OK
- provision/hosts/search?hostname=ACACA - **NOK**

Although `var_dump($_GET)` returns:

```
array(1) {
  ["hostname"]=>
  string(5) "ACACA"
}
```

Contents of the index.php file:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

//With default settings
$app = new \Slim\App;

$app->get('/hosts', function ($request,$response,$args) {
        require_once 'db.php';
        $query= "SELECT * FROM hosts";
        $result = $mysqli->query($query);
        while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $data[]=$row;
        }
        if(isset($data)) {
                header('Content-Type: application/json');
                echo json_encode($data);
        }
});

$app->get('/hosts/search', function ($request,$response,$args) {
        require_once 'db.php';
        //echo var_dump($_GET);
        $hostname=$request->get('hostname');
        echo $hostname;
});

$app->get('/hosts/{macaddr}', function ($request,$response,$args) {
        require_once 'db.php';
        $query= "SELECT * FROM hosts WHERE macaddr='".$args['macaddr']."'";
        $result = $mysqli->query($query);
        $data=$result->fetch_assoc();
        if(isset($data)) {
                header('Content-Type: application/json');
                echo json_encode($data);
        }
});

$app->run();
?>
```

Comment: Have you looked at your logs to see what the error is?

Comment: @BenSwinburne [Mon May 09 03:52:13 2016] [error] [client 172.128.0.2] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Slim\\Http\\Request::get() in /var/www/html/provision/index.php on line 45

Comment: Interpolating user input into a SQL query is a great way to open yourself to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: @alexw You made a point, but this is going to be used internally to boot some machines through PXE. But thanks for the warning anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `get` doesn't exist in `Slim\Http\Request`

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Slim\Http\Request::get() in /slim3/index.php on line
```

You need to use `getParam`

```
$hostname = $request->getParam('hostname');
```